# unaffix event for Bootstrap affix?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-events

I want to combine the affix plugin with the bootstrap navbar-fixed-top class. So far I have got it working then when I scroll past the navbar it gets fixed. But when I scroll back up I want it to go back into static state again. I have seen some code I think from older bootstrap versions and a `unaffix` event. Why is it gone? Can I create one? Or how to accomplish what I am trying here?

```
navbar_secondary = $( '.navbar-secondary:first' );

navbar_secondary.affix( {
    offset: {
        top: function () {
            return (this.top = navbar_secondary.offset().top )
        }
    }
} );

navbar_secondary.on( 'affix.bs.affix', function () { // this is actually the wrong event for this. I want this to fire when its *not* affixed
    console.log('affix');
    navbar_secondary.removeClass( 'navbar-fixed-top' ).addClass( 'navbar-not-fixed' );
} );

navbar_secondary.on( 'affixed.bs.affix', function () {
    console.log('affixed');
    navbar_secondary.removeClass( 'navbar-not-fixed' ).addClass( 'navbar-fixed-top' );
} );
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Figured it out myself. This event names are totally confusing. `affixed-top.bs.affix` is actually the event when it goes back to being not affixed.

```
navbar_secondary = $( '.navbar-secondary:first' );

navbar_secondary.affix( {
    offset: {
        top: function () {
            return (this.top = navbar_secondary.offset().top )
        }
    }
} );

navbar_secondary.on( 'affixed-top.bs.affix', function () {
    console.log('unaff');
    navbar_secondary.removeClass( 'navbar-fixed-top' ).addClass( 'navbar-not-fixed' );
} );

navbar_secondary.on( 'affix.bs.affix', function () {
    console.log('aff');
    navbar_secondary.removeClass( 'navbar-not-fixed' ).addClass( 'navbar-fixed-top' );
} );
```

#### Summary

> **affix.bs.affix** => before fixed positioning is applied to an element
>   **affixed.bs.affix** => after fixed positioning is applied to an element
>   **affix-top.bs.affix** => before a top element returns to its original (non-fixed) position
>   **affixed-top.bs.affix** => after a top element returns to its original (non-fixed) position
>   **affix-bottom.bs.affix** => before a bottom element returns to its original (non-fixed) position
>   **affixed-bottom.bs.affix** => after a bottom element returns to its original (non-fixed) position

Comment: im having the same problem, i found that both events are firing at same time because the names ARE very confusing.  i almost missed the fact that in your unaffix you used affixed-top., as opposed to just affixed., i was trying affixed.bs.affix.  thanks for this, i concurr, it works.

Comment: isn't the `bottom:` value within the function `offset:` supposed to trigger going from affix to affix-bottom, and the class adding and removing automatically gets handled by bootstrap with that?

Comment: +1 Indeed it works. The BS docs say `affixed-top.bs.affix: This event is fired after the element has been affixed-top.` which doesn't give any idea what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Ahnbizcad, I've found that the bottom offset doens't work like that. If you need to handle the unaffix event as redanimalwar was asking, I suggest to set the CSS positioning for each phase explicitly. For example:

```
    ul.affix {
      position: fixed; 
      top: 100px;
    }
    ul.affix-top {
      position: static;
    }
    ul.affix-bottom {
      position: absolute;
    }
```

And then you can define the value of the offset-bottom function like this:

```
    <ul class="list-group navbar_secondary" id="affix-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="500" data-offset-bottom="-4620">
```

So, the function will start a 500 px and stop at your desired point of the scroll.